# Angular View Rendering multiple times in place, why?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-core

Im using the new angular template, and everytime I make a code change, the view render either underneath, on top of, or beneath the existing view, instead of updating it. Does anyone know why? It didnt do this when I created the project,
 but I can't see why it would now.[image]

```
<mat-toolbar style="background:purple">
    <mat-button-toggle (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><i class="material-icons" style="color:white">menu</i></mat-button-toggle>
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav style="width: 20%;">
        <mat-selection-list>
            <mat-list-item>Item one</mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>Item two</mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>Item one</mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>Item one</mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>Item one</mat-list-item>
        </mat-selection-list>
    </mat-sidenav>   
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-sidenav-container>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%;">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - RemoteTrainer</title>

    <base href="~/" />
    <link href="~/dist/deeppurple-amber.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<p>Welcome to your new single-page application, built with:</p>
<ul>
    <li><a href='https://get.asp.net/'>ASP.NET Core</a> and <a href='https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67ef8sbd.aspx'>C#</a> for cross-platform server-side code</li>
    <li><a href='https://angular.io/'>Angular</a> and <a href='http://www.typescriptlang.org/'>TypeScript</a> for client-side code</li>
    <li><a href='https://webpack.github.io/'>Webpack</a> for building and bundling client-side resources</li>
    <li><a href='http://getbootstrap.com/'>Bootstrap</a> for layout and styling</li>
</ul>
<p>To help you get  started, we've also set up:</p>
<ul>
    <li><strong>Client-side navigation</strong>. For example,  click <em>Counter</em> then <em>Back</em> to return here.</li>
    <li><strong>Server-side prerendering</strong>. For faster initial loading and improved SEO, your Angular app is prerendered on the server. The resulting HTML is then transferred to the browser where a client-side copy of the app takes over.</li>
    <li><strong>Webpack dev middleware</strong>. In development mode, there's no need to run the <code>webpack</code> build tool. Your client-side resources are dynamically built on demand. Updates are available as soon as you modify any file.</li>
    <li><strong>Hot module replacement</strong>. In development mode, you don't even need to reload the page after making most changes. Within seconds of saving changes to files, your Angular app will be rebuilt and a new instance injected is into the page.</li>
    <li><strong>Efficient production builds</strong>. In production mode, development-time features are disabled, and the <code>webpack</code> build tool produces minified static CSS and JavaScript files.</li>
</ul>
<button mat-fab>Click Me</button>
<mat-slider min="1" max="5" step="0.5" value="1.5"></mat-slider>
```

Comment: [Code please](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/). Also, if it's not related to C# or ASP.NET Core, please remove those tags as they're not relevant. Without code I can't work out if they are relevant or not.

Comment: I haven't made any changes to the router outlet or shared layout. I thought that I had included it in the title, but this is the new angular template in .NET Core 2.

Comment: We can only guess the issue and solution without seeing the code. And if doesn't work you will be asking the same question again. You can check if you are reusing the outer or shared layout in the child view.

Comment: Can you share the code which displays `Hello world` and the view which uses the outer view?

Comment: Can you include the full steps to reprodue the issue? My .NET Core 2 Angular template (from the latest updated VS2017) looks very different to your screenshot.

Comment: It didn't do this when I created the project. All I've done since then is install a material design ui library and apply some of the widgets.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I found the answer to my question elsewhere. The problem is caused by including the browser animation module. Adding oldRootElem!.remove(); underneath oldRootElem!.parentNode!.insertBefore(newRootElem, oldRootElem); in boot.browser.ts fixes the issue by disposing of the old view after appending the new one.